# Better way to diagnose missing DLL/assembly from my installer for my .NET app?

Tags: .net, windows, dll

I occasionally add a new component/DLL to my .NET app (C#, C++/CLI) and then forget to add the DLLs/assemblies it requires to my installer.   The installed app does not run (of course).  Doesn't even make anything show up in Task Manager.  There's not even a Windows error dialog about a missing DLL that one often gets with legacy Win32 applications.

I usually figure it out by comparing directory file lists in Windows Explorer but is there another way to figure out what's missing?  Something that would tell me, "You are missing "foo.dll"?

I've tried the ancient, legacy Dependency Viewer utility ("Depends.exe") but that doesn't help.

I tried making VS2019 debug the installed .EXE from disk, so I could watch the debugger complain about what's missing, but I'm embarrassed to say that I cannot figure out how to do it.

I even tried "debugging" one of my unmanaged C++ DLLs (which my app loads via C++/CLI) and setting the installed .EXE as the target.  That doesn't work either;  It tells me that my DLL was not a valid win32 application.  (I remember doing that with regsvr32.exe in VS way back when debugging registering COM DLLs...)

Is there a better way?  Or should I just compare files?

Comment: Win10 no longer displays the WER crash dialog.  Use Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer, Windows Logs > Application to find the crash notification back.

Comment: Perfect. There is it is.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.